# Working .mp4 video file after a while get corrupted

Tags: php, html, video, streaming

Usually i upload video files on my server (no problem in upload or with audio/video codec or container) and all of a sudden after a random time some files get corrupted and act like the one at that link http://www.animestream.it/e2737-Dakara_Boku_wa,_H_ga_Dekinai-01 (http://www.animestream.it/anime/dakarab/DakaraB_Ep_01.mp4)
This video and all the ones in the same folder act like this, but older videos (even videos that has been on the same server for 2 years) not having this problem.
I have already checked this things

- File permissions (R-X)
- Downloaded file to check if working and it does, perfectly.
- Is not a problem of the client/browser since this file worked till yesterday

Comment: Can you compare checksums with the original and the uploaded file? If they are the same then the issue could be from the server handled the request, if they aren't the same them it's to do with the upload. May help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Don't have the original file but i don't think is the upload since this file has been working since 16/03/2015 it's something that happened in the last day... but since it happened only to the folder of this file and not to other files too is strange :|

Comment: Just checked with Microsoft Edge and it work, still have to test Firefox... so guess is not a video problem

Comment: Act like what? I checked the MP4 and it seemed to work fine for me (I skipped around the timeline but did not see any corruption). Do you have a specific time where corruption shows in that video...

Comment: I've solved, seems like when this file was uploaded chrome supported mp3 audio codec, as of now just aac, so i had to convert the audio.